# How can I track the Network Traffic in macOS by Swift Code?

Tags: swift, macos, networking, frameworks, traffic

I want to track the download and upload connection in macOS, but I am a newbie and I do not know how to get started! Especially I do not know which apple framework I should use to get started!?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use for this [NetworkExtension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension?language=objc). Using it, you can track network traffic.

These actions can also be done with [kext](https://developer.apple.com/support/kernel-extensions/), but Apple is going to [stop](https://www.zdnet.com/article/apple-deprecating-macos-kernel-extensions-kexts-is-a-great-win-for-security/) supporting kext.

[Example](https://github.com/objective-see/LuLu) use kext (macOS firewall).